# In Keras, how to get the exact location of the object detected in the picture which is being tested?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm running a custom CNN built in keras, which predicts if an image has vehicle. The CNN performs a forward pass on each stride of the image, to check for vehicles. So my question is, is there any way in Keras, to get the coordinates of the stride in which the object has been detected, in the image, when calling

`model.predict(test_image)`

Comment: what do you mean by stride?

Comment: The convolution kernel slide

Comment: Still not clear. Do you want to find the location of your detected object or you want to find which neurons activate on the object? Your terminology isn't proper.

Comment: The location of the object.

Comment: Then you have to go for object detection architectures that predict object locations as bounding boxes as well as makes a prediction towards which class it belongs to. You can't expect a classification architecture do that for you. Look for Faster RCNN, YOLO or SSD.